# dd-style parameters to a bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to pass params to a bash script, dd-style.
Basically, I want

```
./script a=1 b=43
```

to have the same effect as

```
a=1 b=43 ./script
```

I thought I could achieve this with:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
   eval "$arg";
done
```

What's a good way of ensuring that the `eval` is safe, i.e. that `"$arg"` matches a static (no code execution), variable assignment?

Or is there a better way to do this? (I would like to keep this simple).

Comment: This is tagged with bash. Do you want a Posix compliant solution, or will you accept bash solutions?

Comment: What the tag says is what I mean :)

Comment: Well you could just parse it as a pattern with a `=` separator and do the assignment with a more carefully constructed eval. Just for safety, for private use, I'd to it as you did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lcd047's solution refactored with a hardcoded `DD_OPT_` prefix:

```
while [[ $1 =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*= ]]; do
  eval "DD_OPT_${1%%=*}"='${1#*=}'; shift;
done
```

[frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz) deserves the credit for most of the refactoring.

I put this in a source file with as global variable:

```
DD_OPTS_PARSE=$(cat <<'EOF'
  while [[ $1 =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*= ]]; do
    eval "DD_OPT_${1%%=*}"='${1#*=}'; shift;
  done
EOF
)
```

`eval "$DD_OPTS_PARSE"` does all the magic.

A version for functions would be:

`DD_OPTS_PARSE_LOCAL="${PARSE_AND_REMOVE_DD_OPTS/DD_OPT_/local DD_OPT_}"`

In use:

`eval "$DD_OPTS_PARSE_LOCAL"`

I made a [repo](https://github.com/pjump/dd_opts) out of this, complete with tests and a README.md. Then I used this in a Github API CLI wrapper I was writing, and I used the same wrapper to setup a github clone of said [repo](https://github.com/pjump/dd_opts) (bootstrapping is fun).

Safe parameter passing for bash scripts in just one line. 
Enjoy. :)

Comment: I like this too, cuz it's explicit (unlike the magical, but better, declare). This removes one nesting level. The shifting inside the loop seems to work, I don't know if it's guaranteed to or not.

Comment: replace $ with =

Comment: @frostschutz It's correct. `name` is matched with `key`, not `arg`.

Comment: but you can get rid of `*=*` and stop substituting key/val where there is no =. (since you were refactoring) :P

Comment: in fact you can get rid of the for loop and the if and use while $1 instead, since you're shifting and all...

Comment: Heh, the proof that brainstorming works. :)

Comment: Harvesting morning ideas: you can even get rid of `key` and `val`, and just write `eval "${1%%=*}"=\${1#*=}`.  But that's pretty much as far as it goes, `eval "$1"` as in @rici's `declare "$arg"` won't work, obviously.  Also beware of setting things like `PATH` or `PS1`.

Comment: I polished it up.

Comment: You might want to take another look at the answer, @mikeserv. I would particularly like to draw your attention to the DD_OPT_ prefix that gets attached to any and all dd-style arguments that are processed. Any other security wholes you see? I believe there are none.

Comment: Thank you - I thought that was the evaluated variable. I appreciate your patience with me - that's pretty glaringly obvious. Anyway, no - other than that imagined one, it looks good. You know though you could extend this to work in any shell with `case`. Probably it doesn't matter, but just in case you didn't know...

Answer (score 16):

You can do this in bash without eval (and without artificial escaping):

```
for arg in "$@"; do
  if [[ $arg =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*= ]]; then
    declare +i +a +A "$arg"
  fi
done
```

**Edit:** Based on a comment by Stéphane Chazelas, I added flags to the declare to avoid having the variable assigned being already declared as an array or integer variable, which will avoid a number of cases in which `declare` will evaluate the value part of the `key=val` argument. (The `+a` will cause an error if the variable to be set is already declared as an array variable, for example.) All of these vulnerabilities relate to using this syntax to reassign existing (array or integer) variables, which would typically be well-known shell variables.

In fact, this is just an instance of a class of injection attacks which will equally affect `eval`-based solutions: it would really be much better to only allow known argument names than to blindly set whichever variable happened to be present in the command-line. (Consider what happens if the command line sets `PATH`, for example. Or resets `PS1` to include some evaluation which will happen at the next prompt display.)

Rather than use bash variables, I'd prefer to use an associative array of named arguments, which is both easier to set, and much safer. Alternatively, it could set actual bash variables, but only if their names are in an associative array of legitimate arguments.

As an example of the latter approach:

```
# Could use this array for default values, too.
declare -A options=([bs]= [if]= [of]=)
for arg in "$@"; do
  # Make sure that it is an assignment.
  # -v is not an option for many bash versions
  if [[ $arg =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*= &&
        ${options[${arg%%=*}]+ok} == ok ]]; then
    declare "$arg"
    # or, to put it into the options array
    # options[${arg%%=*}]=${arg#*=}
  fi
done
```

Comment: It won't work with something like `a= b`

Comment: @cuonglm: Why not? (Of course, you need to quote the argument on the command line)

Comment: you mean 'declare a= b' is valid?

Comment: @cuonglm: No, it's not. But `declare "a= b"` is just fine.

Comment: The regex seems to have the brackets wrong.  Perhaps use this instead: `^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*=`?

Comment: The bracketing is off. Otherwise, I think this is the solution I was looking for. It doesn't filter out the processed params but that's easy to add (and I didn't even ask for it).

Comment: Actually, I think it should be like this: `^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*=.` . This avoids matching `foo=`.

Comment: @lcd047: `foo=` is the only way to set foo to the empty string, so it should be allowed (IMHO). I fixed the brackets, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, more brain wandering: I think `[:alpha:]` and `[:alnum:]` are locale-dependent.  Is something like `â` a valid variable name?

Comment: `declare` is about as dangerous as `eval` (one may even say worse as it's not as apparent that it is as dangerous). Try for instance to call that with `'DIRSTACK=($(echo rm -rf ~))'` as argument.

Comment: @lcd047, `bash` allows `[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*` for variable names, but currently has a bug in that it doesn't work for multibyte characters. So yes, `â` is a valid variable name but only in locales where that's expressed as a single byte.

Comment: @lcd047: Yes it is, if you're in an appropriate locale. Such locales are rare these days, though, because in UTF-8 â is multibyte and the id rules are for single-byte characters. This may change someday.

Comment: @lcd047, also note that `[a-z]` matches `â` in most locales (and not ź as that comes after `z`), but it doesn't match letters from other alphabets (which bash allows if they are single-bytes like in locales with cyrillic single-byte charsets).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: That's a good point. Small edit, although there are still probably corner cases.

Comment: Could you clarify the `+` switches please?

Comment: @PSkocik: How's that?

Comment: @PSkocik: `+x` is "not `-x`".  `-a` = indexed  array, `-A` = associative array, `-i` = integer variable.  Thus: not indexed array, not associative array, not integer.

Comment: Alternative to using a hash, you could prefix the variables like `myscript PATH=b` would assign `b` to `$myscript_PATH`. Then, you could make it work with POSIX syntax.

Comment: @rici Very nice! I'd want to do that anyway, so I think the refactored lcd047's solution will still come in handy.

Comment: Note that with the next version of `bash`, you may need to add `+c` to disable compound variables or `+F` to disable floating ones. I'd still use `eval` where you know where you stand.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: If we're lucky, the next version of `bash` will allow `declare +X` which bans any form of evaluation of `key=val` arguments :) But perhaps that's asking for too much. I'm standing with the suggestion of only using known names, rather than allowing any random name. (The PS1 example seems to me the clearest, since no form of preventing evaluation at the point of assignment will help, but I'm sure there are others.)

Comment: Note that there's some improvement comming, see [that thread on the bash-bug mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/22737).

Comment: *You'd rather use an associative array of named arguments which might set variables only if their names are in an array of valid arguments?* Well, you're in luck. You get that featureset without any `bash` bloat - just call up a `dash` shell and define a function. Redefine same within the body of the function itself - without any danger of executing arbitrary shell code if its name does not fit a form. In fact, the shell will flatly refuse any assignment into that namespace as the result of an expansion excepting a predefined shell `alias`. What's more - the backend is  a very fast hash table.

Answer (score 9):

A POSIX one (sets `$<prefix>var` instead of `$var` to avoid problems with special variables like `IFS`/`PATH`...):

```
prefix=my_prefix_
for var do
  case $var in
    (*=*)
       case ${var%%=*} in
         "" | *[!abcdefghijiklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_]*) ;;
         (*) eval "$prefix${var%%=*}="'${var#*=}'
       esac
  esac
done
```

Called as `myscript x=1 PATH=/tmp/evil %=3 blah '=foo' 1=2`, it would assign:

```
my_prefix_x <= 1
my_prefix_PATH <= /tmp/evil
my_prefix_1 <= 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Classic Bourne shell supported, and Bash and Korn shell still support, a `-k` option.  When it is in effect, any '`dd`-like' command options anywhere on the command line are converted automatically into environment variables passed to the command:

```
$ set -k
$ echo a=1 b=2 c=3
$
```

It's a bit harder to be convincing that they're environment variables; running this works for me:

```
$ set -k
$ env | grep '^[a-z]='   # No environment a, b, c
$ bash -c 'echo "Args: $*" >&2; env' a=1 b=2 c=3 | grep '^[a-z]='
Args: 
a=1
b=2
c=3
$ set +k
$ bash -c 'echo "Args: $*" >&2; env' a=1 b=2 c=3 | grep '^[a-z]='
Args: b=2 c=3
$
```

The first `env | grep` demonstrates no environment variables with a single lower-case letter.
The first `bash` shows that there are no arguments passed to the script executed via `-c`, and the environment does contain the three single-letter variables.  The `set +k` cancels the `-k`, and shows that the same command now has arguments passed to it.  (The `a=1` was treated as `$0` for the script; you can prove that, too, with appropriate echoing.)

This achieves what the question asks — that typing `./script.sh a=1 b=2` should be the same as typing `a=1 b=2 ./script.sh`.

Be aware that you run into problems if you try tricks like this inside a script:

```
if [ -z "$already_invoked_with_minus_k" ]
then set -k; exec "$0" "$@" already_invoked_with_minus_k=1
fi
```

The `"$@"` is treated verbatim; it is not re-analyzed to find assignment-style variables (in both `bash` and `ksh`).  I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "BEFORE"
echo "Arguments:"
al "$@"
echo "Environment:"
env | grep -E '^([a-z]|already_invoked_with_minus_k)='
if [ -z "$already_invoked_with_minus_k" ]
then set -k; exec "$0" "$@" already_invoked_with_minus_k=1
fi

echo "AFTER"
echo "Arguments:"
al "$@"
echo "Environment:"
env | grep -E '^([a-z]|already_invoked_with_minus_k)='

unset already_invoked_with_minus_k
```

and only the `already_invoked_with_minus_k` environment variable is set in the `exec`'d script.

Comment: Very nice answer! It's interesting that this won't change PATH, though HOME is changable so there must be something like a blacklist (containing PATH at least) of env vars that'd would be too dangerous to set in this way. I love how this is ultra-short and answers the question, but I'll go with the sanitize+eval+prefix solution as it's still safer and thereby more universally usable (in environments where you don't want users to mess with the environment). Thanks and +1.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash
name='^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$'
count=0
for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
        *=*)
            key=${arg%%=*}
            val=${arg#*=}

            [[ "$key" =~ $name ]] && { let count++; eval "$key"=\$val; } || break

            # show time
            if [[ "$key" =~ $name ]]; then
                eval "out=\${$key}"
                printf '|%s| <-- |%s|\n' "$key" "$out"
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $count

# show time again   
printf 'arg: |%s|\n' "$@"
```

It works with (almost) arbitrary garbage on the RHS:

```
$ ./assign.sh Foo_Bar33='1 2;3`4"5~6!7@8#9$0 1%2^3&4*5(6)7-8=9+0' '1 2;3`4"5~6!7@8#9$0 1%2^3&4*5(6)7-8=9+0=33'
|Foo_Bar33| <-- |1 2;3`4"5~6!7@8#9$0 1%2^3&4*5(6)7-8=9+0|
arg: |1 2;3`4"5~6!7@8#9$0 1%2^3&4*5(6)7-8=9+0=33|

$ ./assign.sh a=1 b=2 c d=4
|a| <-- |1|
|b| <-- |2|
arg: |c|
arg: |d=4|
```

Comment: shift will kill the wrong things if you don't break the loop at the first non-x=y parameter

Comment: @frostschutz Good point, edited.

Comment: Nice job at generalizing it. I think it can be simplified a little.

Comment: Did you get the chance to take a look at my edit?

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. That's the way I like it (+maybe just `shift` instead of `shift 1`). Otherwise thanks!

Comment: @PSkocik Yes.  The argument list shouldn't be changed in the middle of `for arg in "$@"`.

Comment: It worked, though. What I don't like is the case shift loop. You can flatten it by doing the *=* test in `if`. That was the main point of the edit

Comment: @PSkocik I figured how to do away with the `if` (the remaining one is just to print the values).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas The point of the `out` variable is to show the actual value, not the supposed one...

Comment: Then the code would be `eval "out=\${$key}"`. `eval out=\$val` is `out=$val`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `eval out=\$val` is fine since that's how `$$key` is assigned.  `eval "out=\${$key}"` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I settled on `alias` for this kind of work. Here's some of another answer of mine:

---

It can sometimes be possible to separate the evaluation and execution of such statements, though. For example, `alias` can be used to pre-evaluate a command. In the following example the variable definition is saved to an alias that can only be successfully declared if the `$var` variable it is evaluating contains no bytes that do not match ASCII alphanumerics or _.

```
LC_OLD=$LC_ALL LC_ALL=C
for var do    val=${var#*=} var=${var%%=*}
    alias  "${var##*[!_A-Z0-9a-z]*}=_$var=\$val" &&
    eval   "${var##[0-9]*}" && unalias "$var"
done;       LC_ALL=$LC_OLD
```

`eval` is used here to handle invoking the new `alias` from a quoted varname context - not for the assignment exactly. And `eval` is only called at all if the previous `alias` definition is successful, and while I know a lot of different implementations will accept a lot of different kinds of values for alias names, I haven't yet found a shell that will accept a completely empty one.

The definition within the alias is for `_$var`, however, and this is to ensure that no significant environment values are written over. I don't know of any noteworthy environment values beginning with a _ and it is usually a safe bet for semi-private declaration.

Anyway, if the alias definition is successful it will declare an alias named for `$var`'s value. And `eval` will only call that `alias` if it also does not start with a number - else `eval` gets only a null argument. So if both conditions are met `eval` calls the `alias` and the variable definition saved in the `alias` is made, after which the new alias is promptly removed from the hash table.

---

Also useful about `alias` in this context is that you can print your work. `alias` will print a doubly-quoted *safe-for-shell-rexecution* statement when asked.

```
sh -c "IFS=\'
    alias q=\"\$*\" q" -- \
    some args which alias \
    will print back at us
```

#### OUTPUT

```
q='some'"'"'args'"'"'which'"'"'alias'"'"'will'"'"'print'"'"'back'"'"'at'"'"'us'
```